# How to extract from JSON a specific object by its attribute name through iteration and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, geojson

```
var datefilter= getUniqueFeatures(array.features,"Year");
datefilter=JSON.stringify(datefilter);
datefilter=JSON.parse(datefilter);
for (var key in datefilter){
    console.log(key);
```

I am able to isolate by unique features.

I then have them as objects.

This code recognizes the source of my data. However it provides with this output.[image]

What i want is an output based on the highlighted Project_Year attribute. So since i got 12 returned values, i want it to say 2017,2016,2015 and so on. This sounds really easy, but I can't find anything online.

Comment: Is `dateFilter` an array? Are you trying to do `console.log(dateFilter[key])`? Can you include the object at the question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: datefilter is an array from a file.

Comment: Are you trying to get specific property values from an array of objects? That is, the value of `"Project_Year"` property? What is the purpose of `datefilter=JSON.stringify(datefilter);
datefilter=JSON.parse(datefilter);`?

Comment: I want from the array to print the value of Project_Year. This code generates 12 results and each result gives a different answer. Correct!

Comment: I was told JSON.parse turns a string value into an object. I guess by object you are able to highlight each attribute? The result shows all the values highlighted. I just want to pick Project_Year and generate a list. Since my iteration generated 12 values. I want my console.log to generate 12 lines, one for each of the Project_Year value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` and destructuring assignment to get specific properties from an array of objects. `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` do not appear to be necessary.

```js
let dateFilter = [{properties:{Project_Year:2014}}, {properties:{Project_Year:2015}}];

let res = dateFilter.map(({properties:{Project_Year:p}}) => p);

console.log(res);

// or if the property name is also expected
let res1 = dateFilter.map(({properties:{Project_Year}}) => ({Project_Year}));

console.log(res1);
```

Comment: I already have the values generated from the loop. I don't need to input them one by one. I feel my code is complete. It just needs to console.log all Project_Year values. I am having a hard time figuring that out.

Comment: @user35131 If the requirement is to only print the values of `"Project_Year"` you can use `.forEach()`. `dateFilter.forEach(({properties:{Project_Year}}) => console.log({Project_Year}))`

Comment: Is there a way with the previous loop to just add the year line by line? I get results such as  0: {Project_Year: 2014}, 1: {Project_Year: 2015}, 2: {Project_Year: 2016} and so on.

Comment: @user35131 Do you mean to just print the index of the current element of the array? `dateFilter.forEach(({properties:{Project_Year}}, index) => console.log(index, {Project_Year}))`? Or ``dateFilter.forEach(({properties:{Project_Year}}, index) => console.log(`${index}:${JSON.stringify({Project_Year})}`))``?

Comment: I believe so. I just want one line that says 2014, the next line 2013 and so on. These outputs will  be used as headings at an eventual time. I wouldn't want it to say 1: {Project_Year:2015} i just want 2015. Unfortunately both codes don't work for me.

Comment: @user35131 _"These outputs will be used as headings at an eventual time."_ Earlier you stated that you just wanted to print the properties and values at `console`. _"It just needs to console.log all Project_Year values. I am having a hard time figuring that out."_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540728/how-to-extract-from-json-a-specific-object-by-its-attribute-name-through-iterati/54540873?noredirect=1#comment95883048_54540873. How you format the output is a different question that you have not asked.

Comment: The part  where i suggest "at an eventual time" will be asked at a different thread if i can't figure it out. For now I just want the code that i have and it to console.log the Project_Year value only. For example 2014 not {Project_Year:2014}, 2015 not {Project_Year:2015} and so on.

Comment: @user35131 Have you tried the code at stacksnippets at the answer? That is what `res` outputs.

Comment: I tried the code in the snippet. It was good only that it disregarded the loop and it gave me all the values in one drop down.  I want these 12 values separated from one another like in my screenshot, but with the year value. Another problem was that the snippet code gave me the years, but it provided by with this format 1: {Project_Year: 2015}. I'm not sure how to change that. All i want is to instead give me 2015 rather than the brackets with Project_Year.

Comment: @user35131 That is what the output of  `res` is. If you want a formatted _string_ you can use `res.join('\n')` to convert the array to a string joined by the newline character.